# Using existential instantiation (logic)

Tags: logic

Am I using EI right on line 6? (Actually, I'm pretty sure the answer is 'no', and there's a few sketchy lines after that, too. So maybe you could also give a hint about how to do this).

Prove:

1. (∃x)(∀y)(Gxy → Hxy)     (Premise)
2. (∀x)(∃y)￢Hxy        (Premise)

   ```
       ∴ ￢(∀x)(∀y)Gxy
   ```
3. (∀y)(Gay → Hay)     (1, Existential Instantiation)
4. Gab → Hab           (3, Universal Instantiation)
5. (∃y)￢Hay            (2, Universal Instantiation)
6. ￢Hab                (5, Existential Instantiation)
7. ￢Gab                (4, 6, Modus Tolens)
8. (∃y)￢Gay            (7, Existential Generalization)
9. ￢(∀y)Gay            (8, Quantifier Negation)
10. (∃x)￢(∀y)Gxy        (9, Existential Generalization)
11. ￢(∀x)(∀y)Gxy        (10, Quantifier Negation)

Comment: (6) is no good, because you introduced $b$ in (4). But you have essentially the right idea: just put (4) after (6)!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you tell explicitly in your question which system of logic you're working with, rather than leaving it to the reader to reconstruct it from _abbreviated_ names of rules.

Comment: @ZhenLin Please promote your comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The below is verbatim from a comment by Zhen Lin, which was requested by the OP to be posted as an answer, but that wasn't done.*

*The primary intent of this answer is to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

[Zhen Lin wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175785/using-existential-instantiation-logic#comment404218_175785):

> (6) is no good, because you introduced b in (4). But you have essentially the right idea: just put (4) after (6)!